Fire and forget coroutine job
Here is a the actual code in Rxjava. Its a fire and forget database operation
 fun saveResponseToDb() {
    Observable.just(database)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe({ dataBase: DataBase ->
            dataBase.doSomething()
        }, { t: Throwable? -> printStackTrace(t) })
}

What is the Coroutine Equivalent of the same?
I have added a sample equivalent code
 val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    scope.launch {
        dataBase.doSomething()
        scope.cancel()
    }



val job = Job()
    val scope = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.IO)
    scope.launch {
        dataBase.doSomething()
        job.complete()
    }

Is it necessary to cancel the scope or call complete? Which is the right way to do it? What happens when you call or do not call the scope cancel or job complete?
What is the right way to do a fire and forget call in Kotlin-Coroutines?

No you don't have to cancel() or complete(). coroutines can handle it by itself

So both ways are right equivalent of above RxJava code?

Please tag your question with rxjava or provide an explanation of the rxjava code you're using to help others better understand and assist with your issue.

If you really like to run a fire and forget job, and you understand all problems associated with this, then you can use the GlobalScope:
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    dataBase.doSomething()
}

Creating a single-use CoroutineScope which you don't store anywhere, is just a more convoluted way to do the same as using the GlobalScope.
However, if you don't wait for the operation to finish, you don't read its results, you don't observe it for failures, you never cancel it, you don't switch between IO/CPU/UI workloads, you don't fork the task into multiple concurrent subtasks, etc., then you pretty much opted-out from all coroutines features already. At this point the above code is not much different than simply starting a background thread:
thread {
    dataBase.doSomething()
}

Maybe the only difference is that coroutines provide a global, shared thread pool. I'm not very familiar with RxJava, but I suspect it is the same in your original code. You don't really use RxJava framework, you use it merely as a provider of a global thread pool.

database.doSomething() is a suspendable operation. "You can simply start a background thread". Is it what we are doing here ? If you check the Rx-Java code above its the same as our coroutine code right?

What do you suggest to do a fire and forget call in kotlin coroutines? or what is the right way to do it?

I asked about suspending, because you had exactly the same dataBase.doSomething() code in RxJava, so it couldn't be suspendable. But if you mean now you changed the function to be suspend, then we need to start a coroutine. And I already answered how to run a fire and forget coroutine - GlobalScope. Right way is to not use fire and forget operations, but utilize the structured concurrency feature by using a scope with a correct lifetime (depending on your case).

@abhishekmaharajpet I updated my answer and explained why I believe coroutines don't provide you much benefits.

Yes, I was switching from RX to coroutines and trying to find a way to do a similar operation. However starting a new Thread(Runnable) seems pretty outdated coding style. So I am forced to use coroutines, whether or not I am fully utilizing the benefits of coroutines.

@abhishekmaharajpet Threads are not at all outdated. The only reason why they may seem outdated is because they lack features that you intentionally decided to not use anyway :-) We don't get benefits of RxJava/coroutines if we don't use their features.

Well, one possible benefit is if you’re already using coroutines elsewhere in the app, then the thread you use can be one borrowed from a dispatcher instead instantiating a new one.

Well I have no idea about RxJava but I'm using coroutines on my project and it works like this. I have used cancel() only when I need to cancel any already running coroutine process
fun doDatabaseOperation() {
     val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
     scope.launch {
        dataBase.doSomething()
        // here code will execute after database operation completes
        println("database operation completed")
       }
     println("this will execute instantly and will not wait for database operation to complete")
 }


Got it. I understand that viewmodelScope is cleared when viewmodel is cleared, same for lifecyclescope. What about these custom scopes that we create? they do get cleared as and when all jobs within them are completed?

@abhishekmaharajpet What do you mean by "cleared"? There is no "clearing" needed for coroutines. Such scopes are never cancelled and nobody watches them for completion - that's it.

I hope they are not an overhead to the app not affecting any performancce

This isn’t creating significant overhead but it is just slightly more convoluted and redundant code compared to directly using GlobalScope.
